# How to get the value selected from html:options tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Value is not picking up from html:select

```
<html:select property="billSelected">
      <html:option value=""> - Select One - </html:option>
      <html:options property="billList"/>  //billList is a vector
</html:select>
```

And i have a button and its script,

```
<input type="submit" id="handleSubmit" value=" Submit ">
```

**JS :**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#handleSubmit').click(function(){
    var x = document.getElementById("billSelected");
    alert(x);
    alert('${form.billSelected}');          
    });
});
```

billList is populated with 3 values. When i select one of them and click on submit, x and billSelected alerts are giving null. I tried getElemenetsbyName also but no luck. How to get the selected option value ?

Comment: is that `html:select` an element in HTML ?

Comment: it is nothing but <select> which creates a dropdown list

Comment: so why you trying get an HTML element which doesn't have an id ? please add client-side HTML as well, it helps to debug the code easier.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing syntaxes with abandon here. You've got a markup language generating your HTML, and you're trying to use a dynamic value in the javascript alert.

But the idiomatic way to retrieve a selected value is:

```
$('selector-to-get-select-element').val();
```

So,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#handleSubmit').click(function(){
      alert(jQuery('#billSelected').val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript:

```
var ddl = document.getElementById("SelectID");
var selectedText = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;
var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want the option from the select so maybe some jquery when you click on the button. I think it could be would get the selected option

```
$("#billSelected").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which language are you using but anyways make sure in client-side your HTML code be like this, your select element has to have an ID attribute:

```
<select id="billSelect">
      <option value="null"> - Select One - <option>
</select>
```

and easily jquery can select it as the others already said:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#handleSubmit').click(function(){
        var x = $('#billSelect');
        console.log(x);       
    });
});
```

Comment: How can i use options with select? it is not allowing.

Comment: You have to make something like that when your code is compiled and send to client, and the point is about that select.id = "billSelect" nothing else.